# How to print a character code from char*?

Tags: c++, escaping, user-input

I'm getting a character from a user input using [`getchar()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/getchar/), but instead of using `cout` to print the character I want to print the character code, like the one for Return, ESC, etc,  so I can use in my code later to check using a `if`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do this you can cast the char to an int,

```
int charval = (int) mychar;
```

Comment: What's the ASCII character code for `Esc`? And please avoid recommending those antiquated C-style casts. And the cast is not necessary.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit What's the relevance of your question? (The ASCII code for Esc is 0x1B == 27).

Comment: @JimBalter: What do you mean "what is the relevance"? The OP asked about `Esc`, so it is relevant.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit No, the OP did no such thing.

Comment: @JimBalter: `I want to print the character code, like the one for Return, ESC, etc` direct quote

Answer (score 2):

> so I can use in my code later to check using a if.

You don't need to expicitly convert it to an int for that.

```
if(getchar() == char_code)
doSomething();
```

Answer (score 2):

`printf("%d\n", c);` will show you the character code.

Comment: that's a worse answer than my deleted one :)

Comment: I protest! He was asking for the character code.

Comment: @billz This gives the right result, yours gives the wrong result ... so why is this worse? (I would mention something about default promotions of args to vararg functions for edification of the OP and other readers.)

Answer (score 0):

Cast the char as an int and print the int value.